# Make the group from the elements through Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a list to display in the screen through Knockout.js

The data look like

```
[{"ID":12345, "Network":"CNN", "Type":"Film", "Severity":"Warning", "Title":"Demo0"}, 
{"ID":12346, "Network":"Star", "Type":"Film", "Severity":"Warning", "Title":"Demo1"}, 
{"ID":12347, "Network":"CNN", "Type":"Film", "Severity":"Warning", "Title":"Demo2"}, 
{"ID":12348, "Network":"XYZ", "Type":"Film", "Severity":"Warning", "Title":"Demo3"}, 
{"ID":12349, "Network":"XYZ", "Type":"Serial", "Severity":"Warning", "Title":"Demo4"}, 
{"ID":12340, "Network":"Star", "Type":"Serial", "Severity":"Warning", "Title":"Demo5"}]
{"ID":12341, "Network":"XYZ", "Type":"Serial", "Severity":"Warning", "Title":"Demo6"}, 
{"ID":12342, "Network":"CNN", "Type":"Serial", "Severity":"Warning", "Title":"Demo7"}]
```

I have a dropdown in the screen with Film/Serial which does the filter on Film or serial. I am doing the applyFilter for this section.

Now I want to show the data in the screen in group by Network.

When Film is seleted in the dropdown then the below data will shown (along with the drop down)

```
CNN
    12345   Demo0
    12347   Demo2
Star
    12346   Demo1   
XYZ
    12348   Demo3
```

When Serial is seleted in the dropdown then the below data will shown (along with the drop down)

```
CNN
    12342   Demo7
Star
    12340   Demo5   
XYZ
    12349   Demo4
    12341   Demo6
```

I had tried knockoutjs library for groupby but still not able to figure it out.

The jsFiddle for the above one is http://jsfiddle.net/rawatjeet/sL5J3/. The filter part is not working expected so please ignore that one.

Thanks
Jeet

Comment: Can you put together a quick js fiddle showing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsFiddle, look at line 30, the if statement:

```
if (self.choiceTypeSearch().length == 0 || r.Type == self.choiceTypeSearch()) {
```

`r.Type` is an observable and needs to be unwrapped.

```
if (self.choiceTypeSearch().length == 0 || r.Type() == self.choiceTypeSearch()) {
```

For the grouping, you'll need to massage your data structure and create a few computeds.  Just as you have a `filteredChoices` computed, create another one that is just a list of unique `Network` names.  Then in your view, foreach over that list instead and inside that loop, foreach over a filtered (distinct) array of objects by the current Type in the loop.

Look at this jsFiddle by Ryan Niemeyer: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/mXVtN/

Comment: Thanks the r.Type() does the filtering for the filter based on the drop down values. But my other question is on showing the filtered record group by Network. I am looking on the suggestion provided by Hans above.

Comment: Thanks all, I finally able to make this work.
see the jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/rawatjeet/86MUJ/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a computed observable to achieve this. Use array methods to find a unique array of 'types'. Then let the computed observable return an array of arrays: each of the inner arrays should hold only the items of that type.

This is basic JavaScript so I won't write it out, but the trick is to have the original array observable, and use a computed to create a new 'mapping' of this data.